# How to store an object that references several other objects in a specific order?

Tags: python, django

I am developing a Django project with three main classes : class A, class B and class C. Objects from the C class are composed of objects from A and B classes in a specific order. All of them are stored in a MySQL database.

Currently I have :

```
class A(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=250)

class B(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=250)

class C(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    composed_of = PickledObjectField(blank=True)
```

Therefore, to create C objects I do the following :

```
c1 = C()
c1.composed_of = [a1, b4, a1, b1, a2, b2, b3, b4, a2, a5]
c1.save()
```

with a1..a5 being instances of A and b1..b5 instances of B.

This works but is not good at all for two reasons : 1. It is awful when I need to query this field ; 2. If instances of A or B are updated or deleted from the database, the change is not done in the C instances.

Thus my question : how can I make a class with instances referencing instances from other classes, in a specific order ?

I'm using Django 1.8 with Python 2.7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, if you want to reference other models, you should use a many-to-many relationship (`models.ManyToManyField`).

Second, since you have different models you want to reference, you need to use generic foreign keys from the Django [contenttypes framework](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/contrib/contenttypes/), so you can link to any type you want. Now there's a good [blog post](http://charlesleifer.com/blog/connecting-anything-to-anything-with-django/) with code on how to apply this to a many-to-many relationship.

Third, since you want to order the objects of a relationship, you need to provide each relationship with an `order_number` so you'll need a so-called `through` table ([documentation here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ManyToManyField.through)).

It can get quite complicated to manage these ordering numbers when things are changing, there's a good package that has solved this problem: [django-ordered-model](https://github.com/bfirsh/django-ordered-model), but I'm sure there are also others. Look for "ordered many-to-many relationships in Django". You'll probably have to customise for using it on generic m2m relationships.

Comment: I have two questions : 1 - From what I understand, the ManyToMany relationship allows several references to one model, and not several references to two different models. If I am wrong, could you show me an example ? ; 2 - `through` can only sort one model, not two mixed together, can it ?

Comment: oh right, sorry for the oversight on my part. Django has the concept of GenericForeignKey and ContentType, which allow you to make relationships to any type of model. It's what actually used behind the scenes in the permissions system of Django admin. See [this blog post](http://charlesleifer.com/blog/connecting-anything-to-anything-with-django/) that explains it well.

Comment: One thought that comes to mind: Are your models A and B related/similar in any way? Could you for example subclass a common parent class (using [multi-table inheritance](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/db/models/#multi-table-inheritance)? That would make it much simpler to do what you want, since you'd be able to use the parent class as your relationship.

Comment: Sorry I couldn't get back to you earlier. I will look into the links you provided. Multi-table inheritance seems very promising, I'll test it as soon as I can. Thank you!